# C# Enum - How to Compare Value

Tags: c#, enums

How can I compare the value of this enum

```
public enum AccountType
{
    Retailer = 1,
    Customer = 2,
    Manager = 3,
    Employee = 4
}
```

I am trying to compare the value of this enum in an MVC4 controller like so:

```
if (userProfile.AccountType.ToString() == "Retailer")
{
    return RedirectToAction("Create", "Retailer");
}
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

I also tried this

```
if (userProfile.AccountType.Equals(1))
{
    return RedirectToAction("Create", "Retailer");
}
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

In each case I get an Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Are you sure userProfile is not null?

Comment: Why the numbers for the enum values? Enums tend to only need numeric equivalents if you are using them as bit flags and can probably be removed in this case.

Comment: enums can be compared without converting it to string, also the exception might be coming from the instance userProfile

Comment: @Stony looks like it, I am going through to see why userProfile is null

Comment: @ValOkafor just to your knowledge I have added the code to prevent the **if** statement from runing when **userProfile** is **null**

Answer (score 67, accepted):

use this

```
if (userProfile.AccountType == AccountType.Retailer)
{
     ...
}
```

If you want to get int from your AccountType enum and compare it (don't know why) do this:

```
if((int)userProfile.AccountType == 1)
{ 
     ...
}
```

`Objet reference not set to an instance of an object` exception is because your userProfile is **null** and you are getting property of null. Check in debug why it's not set.

EDIT (thanks to @Rik and @KonradMorawski) :

Maybe you can do some check before:

```
if(userProfile!=null)
{
}
```

or

```
if(userProfile==null)
{
   throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(userProfile)); // or any other exception
}
```

Comment: If `userProfile.AccountType` field (property) is of `AccountType` type, then it can't be null, because enums are not nullable in C#. I'd rather bet that `userProfile` itself is null.

Comment: It's probably the userProfile that is null, because AccountType is an enum, thus value type, and cannot be null (unless it is explicitly made Nullable)

Comment: If I would like to compare two Enums. Would it throw some exception?  if yes ,  then what would be exception how it could be handled

Comment: I have got exception while comparing enum values. May I use .Equals to compare rather than " == " to get rid of exception.

Here it is Exception what i got.

Failed to compare two elements in the array. System.Collections.Generic.GenericArraySortHelper`1.BinarySearch(T[] array, Int32 index, Int32 length, T value, IComparer`1 comparer)
   at System.Array.BinarySearch[T](T[] array, Int32 index, Int32 length, T value, IComparer`1 comparer)
   at System.Array.BinarySearch[T]
   at System.RuntimeType.GetEnumName(Object value)
   at System.Enum.InternalFormat(RuntimeType eT, Object value)

Answer (score 11):

You can use [`Enum.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559.aspx) like, if it is string

```
AccountType account = (AccountType)Enum.Parse(typeof(AccountType), "Retailer")
```

Comment: Although technically possible, it's not advisable for speed, localization and other issues.

Answer (score 9):

Comparision:

```
if (userProfile.AccountType == AccountType.Retailer)
{
    //your code
}
```

In case to prevent the **NullPointerException** you could add the following condition before comparing the **AccountType**:

```
if(userProfile != null)
{
    if (userProfile.AccountType == AccountType.Retailer)
    {
       //your code
    }
}
```

or shorter version:

```
if (userProfile !=null && userProfile.AccountType == AccountType.Retailer)
{
    //your code
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked, but I am still getting a Null reference, so I stepping through my Login logic

Comment: @ValOkafor check my explaination

Comment: @ValOkafor as wudzik stated you are probably refering to not-initalized `userProfile`, so either make sure it's initalized before the conditio is checked or add the following code (added to answer).

Answer (score 9):

You can use extension methods to do the same thing with less code.

```
public enum AccountType
{
    Retailer = 1,
    Customer = 2,
    Manager = 3,
    Employee = 4
}

static class AccountTypeMethods
{
    public static bool IsRetailer(this AccountType ac)
    {
        return ac == AccountType.Retailer;
    }
}
```

And to use:

```
if (userProfile.AccountType.isRetailer())
{
    //your code
}
```

I would recommend to rename the `AccountType` to `Account`. [It's not a name convention](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4x252001(v=vs.71).aspx).

Answer (score 3):

You should convert the string to an enumeration value before comparing.

```
Enum.TryParse("Retailer", out AccountType accountType);
```

Then

```
if (userProfile?.AccountType == accountType)
{
    //your code
}
```

Comment: I'm not a fan of enum any more due to all of these conversions. I now just do a public class with public const int for each value, then no conversion needed.